# Copy constructor and normal constructor for non-POD type

Tags: c++

There is this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class KlasaNiePOD{
public:
    int a;
    ~KlasaNiePOD(){}

};
int main() {
    KlasaNiePOD obiekt1; // first case
    std::cout << obiekt1.a << std::endl; // -1075234152
    KlasaNiePOD obiekt2 = KlasaNiePOD(); // second case
    std::cout << obiekt2.a << std::endl; // 0
    return 0;
}
```

Why in the first case 'a' is not initialized, but in second case it is? Shouldn't be called constructor always in non-POD classes?

Edit:

Fragment from assembly:

```
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB960:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x0,__gxx_personality_v0
    .cfi_lsda 0x0,.LLSDA960
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    pushl   %esi
    pushl   %ebx
    subl    $40, %esp
    movl    28(%esp), %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, (%esp) # std::cout << obiekt1.a << std::endl;
.LEHB0:
    .cfi_escape 0x10,0x3,0x7,0x55,0x9,0xf0,0x1a,0x9,0xf8,0x22
    .cfi_escape 0x10,0x6,0x7,0x55,0x9,0xf0,0x1a,0x9,0xfc,0x22
    call    _ZNSolsEi
    movl    $_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
.LEHE0:
    movl    $0, 24(%esp) # Here obiekt2.a = 0
    movl    24(%esp), %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    $_ZSt4cout, (%esp) # std::cout << obiekt2.a << std::endl;
.LEHB1:
    call    _ZNSolsEi
    movl    $_ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_, 4(%esp)
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    _ZNSolsEPFRSoS_E
.LEHE1:
    movl    $0, %ebx
    leal    24(%esp), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    _ZN11KlasaNiePODD1Ev
    leal    28(%esp), %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    _ZN11KlasaNiePODD1Ev
    movl    %ebx, %eax
    addl    $40, %esp
    popl    %ebx
    popl    %esi
    movl    %ebp, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

Comment: Well, your ctor does not intialize a anywhere... so how is it relevant whether it is called or not?

Comment: So why in the second case a is always 0 -- movl $0, 24(%esp) from assembly?

Comment: Because it is an aggregate and you invoke zero initialization. Add an empty default ctor to your class, and you will see this setting to 0 vanish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
KlasaNiePOD obiekt1; // first case
```

This is *default-initialised*; since it doesn't have a default constructor, members with a fundamental type (which includes numeric types) are left uninitialised.

```
KlasaNiePOD obiekt2 = KlasaNiePOD(); // second case
```

The temporary `KlasaNiePOD()` is *value-initialised*; since it doesn't have a default constructor, members with a numeric type are initialised to zero.

Comment: `KlasaNiePOD` is not POD. So the expression `KlasaNiePOD()` creates a temporary invoking the default constructor, which doesn't initialize `a`.

Comment: @Nawaz: The parenthesis cause the instance of `KlasaNiePOD` to be value-initialized. Since `KlasaNiePOD` has no user declared constructor, value-initialization causes the object to be zero initialized.

Comment: @Nawaz : C++03 §8.5/5 disagrees -- "*if `T` is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static data member
and base-class component of `T` is value-initialized*".

Comment: @Nawaz The wording concerning this has changed several times, but in C++11, it clearly says that value-initialization does zero-initialization unless the type has a user-provided constructor.  `KlasaNiePOD` has no user-provided constructor, so `KlasaNiePOD()` does zero-initialization.

Comment: @JamesKanze: It says `if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object
is zero-initialized and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is
called.` I don't see what you're saying here. The quote only says, the implicitly declared constructor is called. That's it. And we know that the implicitly declared constructor doesn't initialize `a`.

Comment: While I believe the standard clearly states that `a` should be zero, running this on MSVC 11 Developer Preview gives you a garbage value.

Comment: @Nawaz : You keep quoting text that specifically says "*the object is zero-initialized*". What on earth are you confused about?

Comment: Then what does it mean `if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is called.`?

Comment: @Nawaz: If there's a base class or member with a non-trivial default destructor, then the implicit default constructor has to call that, and so is itself non-trivial. This happens *after* the object is zero-initialised, so all trivial members will end up as zero.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Hmm.. now that clarified my doubt. Thanks. :-) +1.

Comment: @Nawaz Read what you have quoted, up to the first comma.  `KlasaNiePOD` doesn't have a user-provided constructor, so the object is zero-initialized.  (It's default constructor is trivial, so no constructor will be called, but that's really irrelevant here.  And of course, doesn't change anything, since what makes a constructor trivial is the fact that calling it has no effect.)

Comment: @MikeSeymour One other case where the implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial: if the class has any virtual functions.  (Just mentioning this for completeness.)  (And I'm sure you meant "with a non-trivial default constructor", not "destructor".)

Answer (score 3):

The standard defines several different types of initialization,
depending on context.  Zero-initialization sets all of the members to 0
(converted to the appropriate type, so pointers will be set to a null
pointer value, even if the null pointer isn't all zero bits); no
constructor is called.  Default-initialization calls the default 
constructor, which be default doesn't do anything.  Value-initialization
calls the default constructor if a user defined constructor is present,
but does zero-initialization, followed by the default constructor, if
there is no user defined constructor.  An object whose initializer is
simply `()` (an empty list) is value-initialized.  An object with static
lifetime is zero-initialized before program start (always); if it has a
non-trivial constructor, its constructor will be called sometime later
(but before entering `main`).  All other objects defined with no
initializer are default-initialized.

In your code, `obiekt1` is default-initialized; in this case, a no-op
(leaving the members uninitialized).  `obiekt2` is initialized by copy
of a value-initialized temporary; the value-initialization sets `a` to
0.  (The actual copy may be optimized out, with the value-initialization
taking place directly on the object.)

Answer (score 1):

ISO 14882:2011(e) 8.5.1 :

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
>   constructors (12.1), no brace-or-equalinitializers for non-static data
>   members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause
>   11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

As such, your class is an aggregate.

```
KlasaNiePOD obiekt2 = KlasaNiePOD(); // second case
```

will invoke aggregate and finally value initialization, causing the int to be zero intialized.

Add

```
KlasaNiePOD(){}
```

to your class definition, and you will see that the setting to 0 will vanish (as this will make it not an aggregate anymore).